# Использование PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); в другом классе

Tags: java

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

В сервлете есть переменная out для вывода информации о работе приложения и сообщений об ошибках.

```
  catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("ERR " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

А как использовать эту переменную для аналогичного вывода но в другом классе. Класс в другом пакете.

Comment: Зачем сервлету писать сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете просто передать в конструктор либо в метод этот writer.
Если вам нужно использовать Объект класса PrintWriter возвращаемый одним с методов сервлета(объекта response) в другом классе(не важно,будь-то он в другом пакете) используйте следующее :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Берем writer,чтобы передать другому классу
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

     //Я передаю writer в конструктор класса
    OutFromaClass outClass = new OutFromaClass(writer);
    String out_message = "hello world from a other class";

    //Метод для вывода
    outClass.out(out_message);
}
```

Собственно , возможный импортируемый класс :

```
class OutFromaClass {
private PrintWriter writer_servlet;

public OutFromaClass(PrintWriter writer_servlet) {
    this.writer_servlet = writer_servlet;
}

public void out(String str) throws IOException{
    writer_servlet.write(str);
    writer_servlet.flush();
    if(writer_servlet.checkError()) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
  }
}
```

Если будет исключение в потоке вывода , то мы сгенерируем исключение,которое пробросится методу,который вызвал этот метод.То есть сервлету.А вы прописали блок отлова -

```
  catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("ERR " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Вы просто поместите метод в блок try/catch с методом,который пробрасывает Exception.

```
  try{
      //Тут может быть взрыв!
      outClass.out(out_message);
  catch(IOException ex){
      //ex.getMessage();
  }
```

Да,и мне кажется,что вам стоить почитать об ссылочный переменный.Ибо мне кажется,что вас смутило именно связанное с этим.Когда вы передаете ссылку какую-то,да вот давай в этом примере возьмем,то у нас ссылочная переменная просто КОПИРУЕТСЯ.Что в сервлете объект out будет ссылаться на поток вывода сервлета,что тот PrintWriter,который мы передали в конструктор будет тоже ссылаться на поток вывода объекта response.

Comment: Спасибо! В классе сервлета работает, но если я пищу вызов в другом классе то  outClass.out(out_message); не видится.